# Is it possible to have two screen-share sections on the same page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii, webrtc

I have a page with a section which users can use to share their screen and it is working perfectly fine (I am using WebRTC in Yii framework).

I need to have a second section on the same page which will allow other user to share his/her screen so that two users can share their screen with all other users in the room. I try to draw it out:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|                             My Page                                |
|                                                                    |
|      -------------------------    -------------------------        |
|      |                       |    |                       |        |
|      |                       |    |                       |        |
|      |    user-1 screen      |    |    user-2 screen      |        |
|      |   is being shared     |    |   is being shared     |        |
|      |                       |    |                       |        |
|      |                       |    |                       |        |
|      -------------------------    -------------------------        |
|                                                                    |
|                                                                    | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes, of course.  You just need to setup a separate PeerConnection for user-2.  (Don't go through the hassle of using the same PeerConnection as the addStream functionality is a little cumbersome.)

Comment: How would you go about doing that? I have one that's currently working fine but when tried to add the second one it doesn't work.

Comment: It's probably just a matter of debugging.  You have two separate peer connection variables (pc1 and pc2), yes?  Make sure the ice candidates are added correctly, i.e., you're not adding the same ice candidates for pc1 as for pc2.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't using ice candidates. I will try that and see if it works.